# Перемещение ячейки bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

На странице есть меню:

```
<body>
...
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<ul>
...
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Каким образом можно переместить это меню сразу после тега body для мобильных устройств (xs)?

Comment: <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<ul>
...
</ul>
</div>
</div>

Comment: правка: bootstrap*

Comment: а назначить class и сделать display:none; а  в @media screen показать этот блок но скрыть основной - нельзя ?

Answer (score 1):

В разделе [Responsive Utilities](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp) описаны классы, которые помогают на определенных разрешениях показывать определённые блоки.
Например, класс `.visible-xs-*` будет виден только на небольших экранах (<768px).

> Classe    Extra small devices Phones (<768px)
>   .visible-xs-* |   Visible
>   .hidden-xs    |   Hidden